# Skill manifest endpoint missing while converting v4 bot to a custom skill

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to convert a v4 bot to custom skill. The bot with all the files is working as expected. But it is missing an */api/skill/manifest* endpoint which is needed for connecting the skill to a virtual assistant.

updating the question

After making changes in the BotController.cs file my bot is throwing 
`post 500 directline.PostACtivity error`

Before editting BotControler.cs file was like this

```
[Route("api/messages")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter Adapter;
        private readonly IBot Bot;

        public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
        {
            Adapter = adapter;
            Bot = bot;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
            await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
        }
    }
```

After changing it like this, bot is not responding

```
 [ApiController]
public class BotController : SkillController
{
    public BotController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, BotSettingsBase botSettings)
        : base(serviceProvider, botSettings)
    { }
}
```

Also found an error here BotController.cs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Add packages

Add [`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions/) and [`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills/) NuGet packages.

#### Create a SkillAdapter

```
public class MySkillAdapter : SkillAdapter
{
    public MySkillAdapter(
        BotSettings settings,
        ICredentialProvider credentialProvider,
        BotStateSet botStateSet,
        ResponseManager responseManager,
        IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient,
        UserState userState) : base(credentialProvider)
    {
        //
        Use(new SkillMiddleware(userState));
    }
}
```

#### Add transients to `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddTransient<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, DefaultAdapter>();
services.AddTransient<SkillAdapter, MySkillAdapter>();
```

#### Update `BotController.cs`

Now you can update your controller to derive from `SkillController` which contains `api/skill/messages` and `api/skill/manifest` endpoints.

```
[ApiController]
public class BotController : SkillController
{
  public BotController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, BotSettingsBase botSettings)
      : base(serviceProvider, botSettings)
  { }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error after updating BotController.cs file. I've updated it in the question.

Comment: @User96 Why did you edit the file like this? It is not the same as the one in my answer. Neither similar to the one you had before.

Comment: Please find the error that I'm getting while adding the same code you have given in your answer.

Comment: I see, and using the one you wrote before with the correct implementation of the current SkillController the bot isn't responding? You also added the adapter and the transients to your startup?

Comment: I'm new to botframework, so not much familiar with Adapters also. The CustomSkillAdapetr.cs and DefaultAdapter.cs files were already there in the custom skill template on which I have started working. I had to add transients, but instead of services.AddTransient<SkillAdapter, MySkillAdapter>(); which showed some error, I used services.AddTransient<SkillWebSocketBotAdapter, CustomSkillAdapter>();

Comment: SkillAdapter is missing in my project. Do I need to add any other NuGet packages other than  Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions and Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills  ?